# how to use the same form control name to multiple dropdowns in angular

Tags: angular

im using the dropdown, in that if i select the freezer the another dropdown will appear, for the two dropdowns im using the same formcontrolname inorder to pass the value to the backend with the same header,but due to the use of same form control name  after selecting the value of the second dropdown it is diappearing. how can we fix this , how can we pass the value with the same header from two different dropdowns.

html

```
   <mat-form-field  fxFlex="28%" class="searchForm" >
        <mat-label>Entity Name</mat-label>
         <mat-select class="form-control" formControlName="entityName" id="entityName">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let entityName of entityNames" [value]="entityName.value">
               {{entityName.viewValue}}
            </mat-option>
         </mat-select>
       </mat-form-field>
          <mat-form-field  fxFlex="28%" class="searchForm"*ngIf="auditForm.get('entityName').value=='freezer'" >
            <mat-label>Storage</mat-label>
             <mat-select class="form-control" formControlName="entityName" id="entityName">
                <mat-option *ngFor="let freezer of freezers" [value]="freezer.value">
                   {{freezer.viewValue}}
                </mat-option>
             </mat-select>
           </mat-form-field>
```

ts

```
 public entityNames:any=[
    {viewValue: 'User', value: 'User'},
    {viewValue: 'Receivable',value: 'Receivable'},
    {viewValue: 'Location',value: 'Location'},
    {viewValue: 'Item', value: 'Item'},
    {viewValue: 'Freezer', value:'freezer'},
    {viewValue: 'Refrigerator', value:'refrigerator'},
    {viewValue: 'Incubator', value:'incubator'},
    {viewValue: 'Open Storage', value:'open_storage'},
   ];
 public freezers:any=[
     {viewValue: ' Rack', value:'freezer_rack'},
     {viewValue: ' Row', value:'freezer_row'},
     {viewValue: ' Section', value:'freezer_section'},
     {viewValue: ' Shelf', value:'freezer_shelf'},
     {viewValue: ' Slot', value:'freezer_slot'},
   ]; 
 this.auditForm = this.fb.group({

      entityName:[''],

    })
```

i need to pass the value to the entityName with two dropdowns , how can we pass the value?

Answer (score 0):

You can not use the same formControlName in two inputs.

Re-think your code. You can use an auxiliar formControl -and use [formControl]="mynewControl"-, or use [ngModel]

```
<input [ngModel]="form.get('entityName').value" 
       (ngModelChange)="form.get('entityName').setValue($event)
       [ngModelOptions]="{standalone:true}">
```

Comment: how can we pass the value from the  storage dropdown to the entityName of the form

Comment: sorry, My answer is stupid. Well, one thing is use two inputs with the same value, but you has a select with differents options list. i'ts impossible. Remember, not all enclosed between `<form [formGroup]="form">` and `</form>` must belong to the formGroup. You can use [(ngModel)] with a **new variable** or a formControl  than not belong to the form